# What raised mudra is depicted on the Buddha rupa at the London Peace Pagoda and what does it mean?

Tags: buddha, mudra, rupa

[image: Buddha on the London Peace Pagoda]

What raised mudra is depicted on [this particular Buddha rupa](https://www.geograph.org.uk/photo/2619700) at the [London Peace Pagoda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peace_Pagoda#London,_England) and what does it mean? Also, which Buddha is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This guide -- [The Battersea Park Peace Pagoda](https://sequinsandcherryblossom.com/2014/08/17/the-battersea-park-peace-pagoda/) -- says,

> In this statue the Vitarka Mudra, associated with explaining the Buddha’s teachings, with the right hand right raised and the tips of the forefinger and thumb touching, is combined with the Tarjani Mudra for warding off evil, with forefinger and little finger outstretched.

Comment: Thanks! Interesting the different variations for each mudra compounded with the addition of the variations from another mudra give all kinds of possibilities for meanings

Comment: Yes thanks for the question. The mudras chosen seem wonderfully appropriate, fitting the intention of the creators of the pagoda.